# Cannot use :paste in Scala 3.0.0 REPL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

In Scala 2.x I use `:paste` for multi-line pasting. I am using Scala 3.0.0 and using the same approach throws an error:

```
scala> :paste
Unknown command: ":paste", run ":help" for a list of commands
```

I tried the following but I don't know how to execute when I'm done writing the code:

```
scala> if (true)
     |   println("that was true")
     | else
     |   print("false")
     |
```

I found at https://users.scala-lang.org/t/solved-cannot-use-paste-in-scala3-repl/7587 that

> :paste is not implemented but it’s also not really needed because
> multi-line pasting is supported by the scala 3 REPL.

How do I execute the multi-line code in Scala 3?

**UPDATE 1:**

I achieved it by using

```
scala> if (true)
     |   println("that was true")
     | else
     |   print("false")
     | ;
that was true
```

Is there another way to execute the multi-line code, without having to write `;`?

Comment: You can surround everything with a block; `{}`

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to execute when I'm done writing the code

For your particular case, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again in the REPL:

```
scala> if (true)
     |  println("that was true")
     | else
     |  print("false")
     | // <-- press enter here again
that was true
```

#### Blocks in the REPL

You can also enter a block delimited by curly braces (i.e., `{` and `}`) in the REPL. Blocks come in handy for implementing sealed traits in the REPL.

Let's try to define the objects `A` and `B` that extend the sealed trait `Level`:

```
scala> sealed trait Level
// defined trait Level
                                                                                      
scala> object A extends Level
-- [E112] Syntax Error: --------------------------------------------------------
1 |object A extends Level
  |       ^
  |       Cannot extend sealed trait Level in a different source file
  |
  | longer explanation available when compiling with `-explain`
1 error found
```

The REPL treats the definitions of `Level` and `A` as if they were located in different files. That isn't the case if you group them inside a block:

```
scala> {
     | sealed trait Level
     | object A extends Level
     | object B extends Level
     | }
// defined trait Level
// defined object A
// defined object B
```